# How to properly import data from Google Drive to Google Colab Notebook?

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, pydrive

I know this is very simple, but I need some directions.

I have a Jupyter Notebook that I used to run on my local Linux machine. The notebook has some deep learning training code that imports dataset, processing and training and stuff.

In my local machine I have my dataset located at

```
'/home/USERNAME/Workspace/Final Year Project/input'
```

This **input** folder has two sub folders **train** and **test**
When I run the notebook on my local machine it runs perfectly, but my system has some limitations so I chose to use Google Colab instead.

But the main issue I am facing is how to import the same dataset in Colab? Like I know it could be done using Google Drive but how?

Currently I am loading my dataset in my **numpy** array using the file path

> If I upload my dataset to Google Drive how could I use this file path?

For example to get the training data I use the below function which takes the file path as parameter

```
# Get training data
def get_X_data(path, output_shape=(None, None)):
    '''
    Loads images from path/{id}/images/{id}.png into a numpy array
    '''
    img_paths = ['{0}/{1}/images/{1}.png'.format(path, id) for id in os.listdir(path)]
    X_data = np.array([skimage.transform.resize(skimage.io.imread(path)[:,:,:3], output_shape=output_shape, mode='constant', preserve_range=True) for path in img_paths], dtype=np.uint8)  #take only 3 channels/bands

    return X_data
X_train = get_X_data(train_path, output_shape=(img_height,img_width))
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to sync your files to Drive on macOS or Window is to install the Drive sync client --
https://www.google.com/drive/download/

Then, in Colab, you can mount your Drive files using the following command:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Afterward, your files will appear in the path `/content/drive/My Drive` and in the file browser like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this code there after uploading your dataset in Drive

- Make sure that this chunk of code is copied in another cell before
  execution of the code cells you have
- First run this code in a cell `!pip install -U -q PyDrive`

Then run this part of code

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
file_id = 'REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_FILE_ID'
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})
print('Downloaded content "{}"'.format(downloaded.GetContentString()))
```

**Note:** For every file in Google drive you will have a file_id that is get the ***shareable link*** of that file and last part of that link you will get a file id. A file ID looks like: **laggVyWshwcyP6kEI-y_W3P8D26sz**.

- Replace this file_id in the code

Comment: If it helps please make it as verified answer